# Setting Title in SAS to a cell value

Tags: sas, title

SAS - I want to set the title of my chart to a specific cell value, say the first observation of my Rate_ID column. How could I do this?

Comment: How are you producing your chart?  Are you using gplot? Proc sgrender?  Is it just using the `title` statement for the chart title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If as @Robert Penridge suggests, you're using a SAS procedure which uses `title` statements for titling, use SAS Macro:

```
data _NULL_;
  set my_dataset (obs=1 keep=rate_id);
  call symputx('mytitle',rate_id);
run;

title "&mytitle.";
/* Insert chart code below */
```

This code gets the first observation from your dataset and sets up a macro variable called `mytitle` containing the value of `rate_id` for that observation. Then you can pass the value to the `title` statement.

I've used `obs=1` to restrict to one observation, and `keep=rate_id` to improve efficiency if you're dealing with a dataset with lots of columns. Also, `call symputx` will trim the value of `rate_id`, removing all leading and trailing whitespace from the resulting macro variable.